# How to make a controller submit predetermined data, when it's accessed?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I think this is a pretty simple solution, but i'm probably missing something.

Basically a user clicks on a link that takes them to another controller and action. Lets say

```
http://website.com/controller/add/12/32/45/63
```

I then want that controller to get these ids, and submit them directly to the database, and then redirect the user back to the front page.

Here's what I have so far

```
    public function add($s_id, $t_id, $c_id, $f_id) {
        $u_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

        $data = array(
            'Favorite' => array(
                's_id' => $s_id,
                't_id' => $t_id,
                'c_id' => $c_id,
                'f_id' => $f_id,
                'u_id' => $u_id
            )
        );
        $this->Favorite->create($data);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//the code you are doing is not secure... sanitize all the params before working with them.

```
  public function add($s_id, $t_id, $c_id, $f_id) {
        $u_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

        $data = array(
            'Favorite' => array(
                's_id' => $s_id,
                't_id' => $t_id,
                'c_id' => $c_id,
                'f_id' => $f_id,
                'u_id' => $u_id
            )
        );
        $this->Favorite->save($data);
    }
```

or

```
 public function add($s_id, $t_id, $c_id, $f_id) {
        $u_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

        $data = array(

                's_id' => $s_id,
                't_id' => $t_id,
                'c_id' => $c_id,
                'f_id' => $f_id,
                'u_id' => $u_id

        );
        $this->Favorite->save($data);
```

Those will save on a new row..

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I don't sanitize/validate until after I get the function working. Since I didn't even know if my code was correct.

Comment: Sanitising should not be needed when using `Model::save()` CakePHP will handle that for you. (You *may* need validation rules to check if the provided values are *valid*)

Comment: However, you seem to be using a regular link to **save** data. This is asking for trouble (for example, Google indexing your site will attempt to **insert** data in your database if it visits those links). When saving data, you should always use `POST` or `PUT`. You can achieve this with `FormHelper::postLink()` (see the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postLink)). Also *check* that the `POST` method is used, using `if($this->request->is('post')) ...`